# Как сделать так, чтобы после обработки каждой строки в .csv файле он удалял предыдущую?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

задался вопросов в своём программном обеспечении, как сделать написать код в Python так, чтобы он читал файл .csv и брал из него каждую строку и работал с ней, а после работы удалял автоматически её и переходил к следующей, но при этом чтобы строка с которой он работал не оставалась пустой а сдвигала строку ниже - вверх и скрипт снова работал с ней и делал этот алгоритм пока его не остановят?

Comment: Есть библиотека `pandas` или например встроенная `csv`

Comment: У вас явно "проблема XY", сначала объясните **зачем** вы пытаетесь это сделать? Мне кажется вы пытаетесь решить какую-то задачу не тем способом, которым она должна решаться.